# Mail.java:18: error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, email

```
import java.security.Security;  

 import java.util.Properties;  


 import javax.mail.Message;  

 import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;  

 import javax.mail.Session;  
 import javax.mail.Transport;  

 import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;  

 import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;  

 import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;  

 import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;  



 public class SendMail {  



 public String to;  

 public String subject;  

 public String text;  



 SendMail(String to, String subject, String text){  

      this.to = to;  
      this.subject = subject;  

      this.text = text;  

     }  



public void send() throws NoSuchProviderException, AddressException{  



  try 

        {  

           Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());  

           Properties props=new Properties();  

           props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol","smtp");  

           props.setProperty("mail.host","mail.epro-tech.com");  

           props.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");  

           props.put("mail.smtp.port","465");  

           props.put("mail.debug","true");  

           props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port","465");  

           props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  

           props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback","false");  

           Session session=Session.getDefaultInstance(props,new GJMailAuthenticator());  

           session.setDebug(true);  
           Transport transport=session.getTransport();  

           InternetAddress addressFrom=new InternetAddress("itopstest@epro-tech.com");  

           MimeMessage message=new MimeMessage(session);  

           message.setSender(addressFrom);  

           message.setSubject(subject);  

           message.setContent(text,"text/html");  

           InternetAddress addressTo=new InternetAddress(to);  

           message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,addressTo);  

           transport.connect();  

           Transport.send(message);  

           transport.close();  
           System.out.println("DONE");  



         }  

         catch(Exception e)  

         {  



           e.printStackTrace();  

         }  

    }  

 }  

class GJMailAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator{  

     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()  

     {  

         return new PasswordAuthentication("itopstest@epro-tech.com","Ops@890T");  



     }  

 } 



 public class Mail extends SendMail {  



     public static void main(String[] args) {  



         String to = "noreply@eprocorp.com";  

         String subject = "Test";  

         String message = "A test message";  



         SendMail SendMail = new SendMail(to, subject, message);  

                 try 

                 {  

                     SendMail.send();  

                }  

                 catch (Exception e)  

                 {  

                     //  

                 }  

     }  

 }
```

receiving the error

```
Mail.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
         SendMail SendMail = new SendMail(to, subject, message);
         ^
  symbol:   class SendMail
  location: class Mail
Mail.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
         SendMail SendMail = new SendMail(to, subject, message);
                                 ^
  symbol:   class SendMail
  location: class Mail
2 errors
```

can any one plz suggest me how to rectify this

Comment: You're missing a `SendMail` object.

Comment: You should import the `SendMail` class package in `Mail Class`

Comment: @user2053430 Is the SendMail class package  is imported ???

Answer (score 0):

I can see there are problems.

1. Mail class is extending SendMail class which do not have default cunstructor. so either create a default cunstructor in SendMail class or create a parameterize cunstructor in Mail class
2. `SendMail.send();` here i guess compiler is trying to access static method of SendMail class.  create your object like `SendMail sendMail = new SendMail(to, subject, message);` and access send method like `sendMail.send();`
3. Give proper package name to both your classes because your class has common names which may be found in jars.

Answer (score 0):

code already containd a constructor

SendMail(String to, String subject, String text)
     {
      this.to = to;
      this.subject = subject;
      this.text = text;
     }

```
 even at extends in the class Mail i can see the errors
```